# Fortran allocate/deallocate

Tags: performance, memory-management, fortran

I have the following question:
What is the real overhead of allocate/deallocate statements in Fortran90+?
I.e., several medium-sized arrays are allocated inside a loop, like

```
do i = 1, 1000
    allocate(tmp(20))
    tmp(1:20) = 1d0
    call foo(tmp)
    deallocate(tmp)
end do
```

Is it worth allocating a single work array based on the maximal size in this case?

Comment: Whether there is noticeable savings depends on how long it takes "foo" to run.  Is the change worth while? Its either a matter of opinion, or you should measure the run time on your compiler & machine.  Does the change make the code less readable?  If so, is that worth saving milliseconds of runtime?   seconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found that dynamic array allocation within tight loops can really slow down the execution of my code, with valgrind showing that a large percentage of cycles is taken up by `malloc` and `free`. So if `foo` is a very quick function, then it would be worth statically allocating this array. It is easy to see this overhead by profiling using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual.html)'s callgrind functionality (it may be worth reducing the size of your problem as the profiled execution can be at least 10 times slower).

In fortran 2008 there is a nicer solution to this type of problem. You can declare your variables inside a `block` construct with a size determined at run time. This should make it much easier for the compiler to allocate the variable on the stack. However I haven't used this personally and I'm not sure which compilers support it.

Comment: Note: gfortran [supports block constructs](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status)

Answer (score 4):

The overhead of using `ALLOCATE` and `DEALLOCATE` is the same as the overhead of using `malloc()` and `free()` in C. Actually most Fortran compilers implement `(DE)ALLOCATE` as wrappers around `malloc()/free()` with some added bookkeeping, inherent to all Fortran 90 arrays.

Usually it is better to preallocate a big enough scratch array and use it in tight loops instead of constantly allocating and freeing memory. It also keeps the heap from getting fragmented which could lead to allocation problems later on (very rare situation but it happens, especially with 32-bit codes).

Comment: Because 32-bit codes have access to only 2 GiB of user virtual address space (or 4 GiB on OS X) shared between heap, stack and memory-mapped files and with badly fragmented heap there just might not be large enough continuous space to provide further allocations of big chunks.